# Highchart how can i give frame like this?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want give some frame on heatmap.

[image]

How can i achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rect` method from `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            this.renderer.rect(100, 100, 50, 50).attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: 'red',
                zIndex: 3
            }).add();
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5x0h9ued/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: If i set rect(0,0),red frame will out of the chart. 
like this https://jsfiddle.net/Willie_LEE/k0of26gm/1/
 how can i let red frame appear x:0 Y:0. if i set rect(0,0).

Comment: I forget setting margin. it's ok